# Silverlight RadGridView validating e.ErrorMessage (force the error message to show)

Tags: silverlight, validation, radgridview

i am using a Silverlight RadGridView (2010) and CellValidating event.

in validating function, i assign an error message (e.ErrorMessage) and e.IsValid = false

Result is that cell becomes red, but error message is shown only when user put mouse over red arrow of cell....is there a way to force error message tooltip (the grid built in one) to come out automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/gridview/row-validation-error-message.aspx